# Error en deployment JavaScript React "Syntax Error: Unexpected token '<' at main.6894d601.js:1:1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y el area de la que estoy encargado funcionaba perfectamente bien, pero al integrar todos los proyectos y que mi dominio sea en /admin, ha salido este error. Probe muchisimas cosas y aun no encuentro la solucion. Cabe destacar que no es un syntax error, ya que localmente funciona y en la nube tambien funcionaba, el error se da al compartir dominio y puerto. (Anteriormente, el deploy fue en mismo dominio pero distinto puerto y funcionaba bien).

Dejo mi index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <base href="http://dominio.com/admin" />
  <script>
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || [];
      w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
      j.async = true;
      j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-NSMPJFZ');
  </script>
  <!-- <script src="http://dominio.com/admin/src/Main.js" type="text/babel"></script> --> 
  <!-- <script src="http://dominio.com/admin/src/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://dominio.com.ar/admin/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2c7be5" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="http://dominio.com/admin/manifest.json" />
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700%7CPoppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dominio.com/admin/index.css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="admin/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="admin/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="admin/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="admin/favicon-16x16.png">
  <title>titulo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NSMPJFZ" height="0" width="0"
      style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <main class="main" id="main"></main>
</body>

</html>
```

En mi package.json tengo lo siguiente:

```
{
  "homepage": "http://dominio.com/admin",
  "homepageOverride": "http://dominio.com/admin/",
  "name": "nombre",
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
...
}
```

y mi manifest:

```
{
  "short_name": "CabapropAdmin",
  "name": "CabaProp Admin",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#2c7be5",
  "background_color": "#edf2f9"
}
```

cualquier ayuda se agradece, llevo 2 dias con esto.

Comment: Hola! Cómo estás? Para empezar, te recomiendo hacer el tour de [Recorrido de Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Por otra parte, estás realizando una extensión para la web store, puede ser? Quedo atento a tu respuesta... Saludos!

Comment: @Inkinvissible Nono, es una web completa. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: En ese bundle no puedes ver a que linea refiere el error?

Comment: No, no me deja, me tira error en linea 1:1

Answer (score 0):

Creo que encontré una posible solución, lo dejo acá por si a alguien le sirve:

Estaba pasando la ruta completa http://url.com/admin y en el BROWSERROUTER le pasaba basename = /admin. Es lo unico que encontre distinto en mi codigo y el recuperado (fuimos a un commit de la semana anterior y recuperamos los cambios, jamas identificamos el error.)